# Python join list every 8 iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

taking in subnet and ip address, performing a logical AND to retrieve the network address.
My question is, how do I return a list of four octets, rather than just have all of the values stored into a list.

Example, my function is printing ['1','1','1','1'...], where as I want to print ['11111111','11111111','11111100','11111111']

```
def logicalAnd(ip, subnet):

test = list()
for ipOctect, subnetOctect in zip(ip, subnet):
    for i,j in zip(ipOctect, subnetOctect):
        octet = (i and j)
        test.append(octet)
print(test)
```

Comment: And what's the input you're passing to your function?

Comment: Show a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, consider using a module (eg `netaddr`) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you just want to chunk the data into groups of 8.  This is done best here:

[How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

mylist = ['1']*32        

print(["".join(i) for i in chunks(mylist,8)])
```

output:

```
['11111111', '11111111', '11111111', '11111111']
```